# Emulating a scala ParStream

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, scala-collections

A not uncommon pattern in Project Euler problems seems to be something equivalent to:

```
Stream.from(1).map(f).takeWhile((_>0)).foldLeft(0L)(_+_)
```

where f is some expensive-to-compute function which returns positive values up to some unknown point, and returns zeros after that.

I do like parallelising things, especially when Scala's parallel collections and `.par` make it so easy.  But in the absence of a ParStream, the best I've come up with is:

```
val BATCH=1024
Stream.from(1,BATCH).flatMap(
  i=>(i until i+BATCH).par.map(f)
).takeWhile((_>0)).foldLeft(0L)(_+_)
```

which doesn't seem very elegant and is sensitive to the choice of `BATCH` value (but can yield x4 speed improvements on my quad-core).

Any suggestions for cleaner ways of achieving the same result ?

Comment: The examples you give aren't equivalent: for example with `val f = 15 - (_: Int)` and `BATCH = 10` the first gives 105 and the second 95

Comment: @Luigi: That's why I qualified it with "returns positive values up to... and returns zeros after that".  e.g It works with def f(x) = 0 max (15-x).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can make it a bit more elegant with something like `Stream from 1 grouped BATCH map (_.par)`, though I'd rather use `Iterator` in this case -- much lighter weight than `Stream`, and it won't fill up REPL's memory as I experiment with it.

Comment: Thanks; I hadn't even noticed the grouped method before!